# Getting Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] in anuglar.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have read every resource I can find on the ngCookies api.  I have also read every resource I could find regarding this injector error.

This is my import stack

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified jquery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>

 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet"     

    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.13/angular.min.js"></script>
      <!-- get cookie api support -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.13/angular-cookies.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.js"></script>



  <script src="/javascripts/angularApp.js"></script>
```

This is the code for my angularApp

```
angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.router','ngCookies'])
.config([
'$stateProvider',
'$urlRouterProvider',
'$cookies', 
function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $cookies) {
```

I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
```

I have checked every explanation of this error and still cannot figure out what is going wrong.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$cookiesProvider` in the config section?

Comment: Not according to this link https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"$cookies" is not available during the configuration phase in AngularJS.
Use it in your controllers, services, factories etc.
Like in [example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies#example) or e.g.:

```
.service('cookiesService', ['$cookies', function($cookies){
    console.log($cookies);
}]);
```